# jquery get, post not working when trying to create automatic website login

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My intention is to make a script to automatically log in to a website instead of having to do the same thing every time i want to get inside..i use it very often.

Before that i am using this code to just check if jquery get is working but its not working..i have index.html file with accompanying jquery library file in desktop and i have checked with all browsers but it doesn't work. Thinking of cross site scripting although i don't fully understand it i tried uploading it to external server and tried running it but still no success. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>jQuery Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.get("http://www.google.com", function (data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            });
        </script>This is Hello World by HTML
        <div id="msgid"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you try to grab something from your server?

Comment: Cross-domain requests are not possible with normal JavaScript. Your best bet for this is probably going to be something like Greasemonkey, which runs on your local browser and has much more extensive rights

Comment: @Pekka, you can do cross-domain get requests using jsonp.

Comment: @Brett to Google.com?

Comment: Sure, why not. Not sure what, if anything, you'll get in return. I'm not saying it's a good idea. @user734861 should be calling his/her own server.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can not be used for GET/POST to cross browser. So,

```
$.get("http://www.google.com", function (data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
```

this will not work.

This is called **same origin policy**. An alternative to this is JSONP, but again it depends on the third party server i.e. whether they support it or not. You can use server side scripting language to grab the cross domain page response and display on your own page.